# Вычисляемые свойства в Angular2

Tags: angular2

Есть ли возможность в Angular2 создать вычисляемые (computed) свойства или что-то на подобии этого, т.е. свойства, зависимые от других, к примеру:

```
@Observe('name', 'surname')
get fullName() {
   return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
}
```

Comment: в принципе ты уже сделал вычисляемое свойство, нужно только убрать `@Observe('name', 'surname')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не используйте вычисляемые свойства, это *bad practice* и на это есть весьма веская причина - Angular перерисовывает все дерево компонентов, и при достаточно большом объеме данных даже один компонент может срезать производительность весьма существенно. Выход - ловите изменения и пересчитывайте данные **один раз**, а не постоянно при перерисовке.

Все это верно, если вы хотите их вывести в DOM (а судя по примеру, так оно и есть).